# How to get a JSON in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, json, casperjs

I have some arguments name1, name2, name3. How can I get a JSON file containing these arguments? I try do this, but I get nothing:

```
var jsonStr = this.evaluate(function(){
       var outjson = {};
       var outjson = {'name1': name1, 'name2': name2, 'name3': name3};
       return JSON.stringify(outjson);
       });
    fs.write('myFile.json', jsonStr, 'w');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no closure for the function, you **evaluate**. You can read something about it here: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

That's why the variables name1, name2 and name3 are undefined, when you **evaluate** the function.

Phantom 2 has the following bug in current releases - an error in a function being **evaluate** rises no exception. In such a case the **evaluate** simply returns **null**.

So, you have an error in you function being **evaluate** and get nothing.

You can try the following example, which prints

> jsonStr: {"name1":1,"name2":2,"name3":3}

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var fs = require('fs');

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {});

casper.then(function() {
    var jsonStr = this.evaluate(function() {
        var outJson = {'name1': 1, 'name2': 2, 'name3': 3};
        return JSON.stringify(outJson);
    });

    this.echo('jsonStr: ' + jsonStr);

    fs.write('myFile.json', jsonStr, 'w');

});

casper.run();
```

and the following example, which prints

> jsonStr: null

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {});

casper.then(function() {
    var jsonStr = this.evaluate(function() {
        var outJson = {'name1': name1, 'name2': name2, 'name3': name3};
        return JSON.stringify(outJson);
    });

    this.echo('jsonStr: ' + jsonStr);
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Thanks, what about case when name1 = 'string1', name2 = 'string2' and name3 = 'string3'. How to get a json-file with these values? I try to do it, but i got empty values..

Comment: @ZaurK I've updated the answer - added saving JSON to a file in the 1-st example.

Comment: May be I don't understand something, but in 1-st example name1': 1 , it is works good, but I need 'name1': name1, when name1 is a value getting dinamically and it's not equal 1.

Comment: I'm sorry) Thanks, I'm understand now about evaluate